# AWS Athena UDF - access to lambda context

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-athena

Is it possible to access the AWS lambda context from within the AWS Athena UDF I'm implementing?

```
public class MyUserDefinedFunctions
        extends UserDefinedFunctionHandler{

...
// access to lambda context ?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can override [handleRequest](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-athena-query-federation/com/amazonaws/athena/connector/lambda/handlers/UserDefinedFunctionHandler.html#handleRequest-java.io.InputStream-java.io.OutputStream-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context-), and save the passed context in an instance field, to be used later by your implementation.  Be sure to call `super.handleRequest` in your override, or your implementation won’t work properly.</strike>

The above won't work, because `handleRequest` is final.  However we can use a delegate pattern to do something similar.  First, implement `MyUserDefinedFunction` so that it takes a `Context` in the constructor, which can be stored away ...

```java
public class MyUserDefinedFunction
        extends UserDefinedFunctionHandler{

    public MyUserDefinedFunction(String sourceType, Context context)
    {
        super(sourceType);
        this.context = context;
    }

    // ... other methods can now refer to this.context

}
```

Then you create a new simple handler which directly implements the `RequestStreamHandler` interface, and on each request creates an instance of `MyUserDefinedFunction`, invoking its `handleRequest` method.

```java
public class MyHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

    @Override
    public final void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {
       MyUserDefinedFunction("sourceType", context).handleRequest(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}
```

Then `MyHandler` becomes your actual Lambda handler.  If `UserDefinedFunctionHandler` consumed a lot of resources to instantiate, then this might not be the best idea, but looking at the [source](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/blob/master/athena-federation-sdk/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/athena/connector/lambda/handlers/UserDefinedFunctionHandler.java), all the constructor really does is store the `sourceType`, so I don't think you're looking at any real overhead instantiating it on each request.

Comment: But @willie-conrad that method is "final" right ? Can it be overriden ?

Comment: Oh dear, I'm sorry I completely missed that  However, I think there's still something you can do ... implement `MyUserDefinedFunction` so that it takes the context in the constructor.  Then create another simpler handler which directly implements `RequestStreamHandler`, instantiates `MyUserDefinedFunction` with the context, and calls `handleRequest` on it.  I'll update my answer to reflect this strategy ...

Comment: Thx! That way solved the problem! :-)